# What is this type of traditional adjustable shelf support called?

Tags: woodworking, wooden-furniture, shelving

[image]

I saw these on a bookcase in a shop today, but don’t know what they are called.

Also is there an easy way to make them, or can they be bought “off the shelf”

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be a "sawtooth shelf support" like the one shown in [this article](http://thepatriotwoodworker.com/forum/topics/how-to-make-an-adjustable-sawtooth-shelf-support-system).